# Getting Molecular Weight for Stoichiometry Calculations

Tags: units, chemistry

I love the units system in Mathematica, it's an extremely useful addition to the language. Unfortunately there are still some sharp corners that I run into on a daily basis. For example, if I want to do a stoichiometry calculation, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
Vol = Quantity[300,"Microliters"]
Concentration = Quantity[2,"Millimolar"]
CdMW = ChemicalData["CadmiumOxide","MolecularWeight"]
mgCd = UnitConvert[Concentration*Vol*CdMW,"Milligrams"]
```

But this does not work, because `"MolecularWeight"` reports units of `AtomicMassUnit`, which Mathematica indicates is incompatible with `"Grams"/"Moles"`, even though in practice (at least for stoichiometry calculations) they are effectively the same.

I have a workaround using the following code:

```
CdMW = Quantity[QuantityMagnitude[ChemicalData["CadmiumOxide","MolecularWeight]],"Grams"/"Moles"]
```

But I find this to be quite inelegant, and somewhat less than readable.

Is this the best way to do this, or is there a better approach?

Comment: I've run into this problem too and each time I just write a helper function as a workaround. Very cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"MolarMass"` property has the same magnitude but the right unit dimensions for this application:

```
CdMW = ChemicalData["CadmiumOxide", "MolarMass"]
(* Quantity[128.413, ("Grams")/("Moles")] *)
mgCd = UnitConvert[Concentration*Vol*CdMW, "Milligrams"]
(* Quantity[0.077048, "Milligrams"] *)
```

As an aside, you can use WolframAlpha in your notebook for some inputs like this.  Here the input string "convert 300 microliters 2mM cadmium oxide to milligrams" works:
[image]

Comment: I was aware of the WolframAlpha technique, but it's a bit brittle, especially if I want to share the notebook with someone. It also gives some strange results occasionally. Try the following query in WolframAlpha `Molar Mass Selenium`

Comment: You are absolutely right, but we are trying to improve. For the selenium example I agree the `"Element"` entity should win over the `"Chemical"` entity with formula Se8.  If you see something which seems wrong there you can click the "feedback" button on the bottom and it will go on someone's todo list

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks for your work on this, it's a very useful feature.

Comment: @JasonB. WolframAlpha is already quite incredible, and I definitely use it for exploratory analysis/finding the correct compound name for something. This may just be my issue, but I don't know of a way to set a variable to the output of a W|A query other than using `%ans` notation. The feedback button is a useful feature that I wasn't aware of, and will make use of in the future.